# .Net Blazor sub app in Web Forms navigation 404

Tags: asp.net, webforms, blazor-webassembly

I'm looking to migrate an ASP Web Forms app to Blazor WebAssembly over time.

Using the notes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65514638/how-to-embed-and-use-blazor-webassembly-in-web-forms) I have been able to get the Blazor WebAssembly app working in a sub folder `blazor` by publishing the app to the folder and setting `base href="/blazor/"`  on the index page in the folder

If I click the buttons in the sample app the navigation works fine, showing http:site/blazor/counter etc. in the browser bar

My issue is that when I try to navigate directly using the URL `http:site/blazor/counter` (or any other page on the Blazor app) I get the standard asp.net 404 error looking for the file / folder.

Is there a way to allow direct navigation in this scenario? I'm guessing it's to do with rewrite rules in web.config but I can't find examples of how to do this.

Comment: were you able to resolve it? I have a similar situation but I'm not even able to make the Blazor app run in a subfolder, you think you can guide me? or tell me where can I find info for that, I've research a lot about it

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to the path not existing on the server since it is not a standard web site with path.

I had the same issue and what I did was to configure Nginx to pass unfound path to the application, which then uses NavigationManager to reach the page it has, if any or handle the 404 itself. I assume this is also valid for other web servers but there might be syntax difference.

In Nginx, tell it to route 404 like this

```
     location / {​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
     }
```

Then in my RoutingIndex.razor, I either send calls directly to the right page or the default page depending on what I receive. (Which is only a basic one for now, as I have yet to really implement it)

```
@page "/{Option}"
@inject NavigationManager NavManager

@*This class allow to catch 404 returned by the server and see if a corresponding page exists
    It is only a basic catch for now, but will allow us to route calls directly to pages when needed.
    It is needed because as a "Website", the Wasm is not a traditionnal one with sub domain that can be called directly.
*@

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public string? Option { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {           
        if(Option.ToLowerInvariant() == "mypage")
            NavManager.NavigateTo("/MyPage");
        else
            NavManager.NavigateTo("/default");
    }
}
```

I have found a link explaining how to configure Apache also here [learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-6.0#apache)

I think you can even let it go directly to the option page sent, if it exists it seems it will be loaded.

So it seems like you can avoid using NavManager, but if it doesn't exists, it will show a blank page(At least its the result I get, but not sure if its only because of the way my project is defined). It might be worth testing if you really need a RoutingIndex like mine. I know I will need mine, because there will be things to be done before sending the user to the page.